# Ideals obtained through ring homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, ring-homomorphism

> Let $I$ be an ideal of S, and let $f$: $R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. Show that $f^{-1}(S)$ is an ideal of $R$.

The solution is,

> Let $g: S \rightarrow S$/$I$ be the quotient map. The kernel of $gf$ is $f^{-1}(I)$, and kernels are ideals.

I do not understand the solution at all. What does $gf$ "look" like, and whs it its kernel $f^{-1}(I)$? Does it involve the First Isomorphism Theorem? Really, any explanation to help me understand this problem would be tremendously helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Do you agree with the proposed new title (the fact that it comes from a midterm assignment is of low informative level... at least in a title)?

Comment: "Does it involve the First Isomorphism Theorem?" yes

Comment: Yes @JeanMarie, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$gf$ means $g \circ f$. That is $gf(r) = g(f(r))$. Does this clear things up for you?

Comment: I can't really visualize $g \dot f$. What is that really doing?

Comment: It just means do $f$ then do $g$.

Comment: If we really want to be specific, $gf$ maps $R \to S/I$